# TFS Git commit user id is different for same user with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015

We are using VS2015 to access Git Repos stored in TFS onprem 2015 update 1.

We have users using both Visual Studio and TortoiseGit for committing and pushing changes from their local repo to the central repository.

In both cases the user is authenticated in windows. It is the same user using an AD account. 
If the user commits via TortoiseGit the name on the commit is "Mycompany\username"
If the user commits via Visual Studio the name on the commit is just "username"

This causes some problems with the Web interface for TFS. If you select the code tab,select a repo, click "History" you have an option to show "My Commits" or "All commits". The web interface only shows the commits performed via visual studio (the one without the AD domain name).

I've checked the settings for TortoiseGit and Git setting in VS and they have the same values: MyCompany\username

Is there a way to prevent this inconsistency so the user can see ALL of their commits regardless of how they were committed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Git commit user ID in the history of the web portal is only related to the setting in VS.

[image]

You can view the result in history tab.

[image]

However, "*my commits*" is  related to the display name of the web portal. If you changed the name and click "*my commits*" , it will only show the commits by the new name.

[image]

Unfortunately, if you want to change the name to `company\user` in the setting of your profile. You will get an error returned as below.

[image]

---

### WorkAround

For your situation:

Method 1: Change  `Mycompany\username` to `username` in both
    settings of TFS and TortoiseGit

Method 2: Use the **Advanced search** in the commits page and specify the
    username in the `user` option such as `Mycompany\name`

[image]